# p4java program to submit file from workspace/client to depot

Tags: java, perforce

I m trying to write a code to submit file(s) from workspace/client to depot in p4java. Using this statement I can add files to "Filespec" from my_branch.

```
List<IFileSpec> Filespec = clientName.addFiles(FileSpecBuilder.makeFileSpecList(new String[] {"//ABCD/DOP/my_branch/..."}),null);
```

How can I submit `Filespec` to depot?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [p4java api doc](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4java/index.html) and the [javadoc](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4java-javadoc/overview-summary.html).
[Here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/core/IChangelist.html#submit%28boolean%29) is the description of the the submit method.

There are some code samples on the [perforce public depot](http://public.perforce.com:8080/@md=d&cd=//public/perforce/p4java/samples/basic/src/com/perforce/p4javademo/&c=H49@//public/?ac=83).
You're interested in [this one](http://public.perforce.com:8080/@md=d&cd=//public/perforce/p4java/samples/basic/src/com/perforce/p4javademo/&cdf=//public/perforce/p4java/samples/basic/src/com/perforce/p4javademo/ChangelistDemo.java&c=LRX@//public/perforce/p4java/samples/basic/src/com/perforce/p4javademo/ChangelistDemo.java?ac=64&rev1=3).

You might also look at other perforce code (for example [this one](https://github.com/fdrueke/ivyp4/blob/master/src/com/orga/ivy/plugins/p4resolver/P4PublishTransaction.java) - see commit method).

Comment: Thank you very much. It has completely solved my problems. @pitseeker

Answer (score 1):

The Perforce samples have moved here https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/perforce_software/p4java/samples/basic